# Linux search file with given name containing string recursively

Tags: linux, string, search, grep

From Linux shell, Let's say I'm in directory `/dir` and I want to find, recursively in all subfolders, all the files which contain in the name the string `name_string` and, inside, the string  `content_string`. `name_string` might be at the beginning, center or end of the file name. How could I do that?

I was trying to sue `grep` as:

`grep -r content_string /dir/*name_string*`

But I haven't been lucky so far.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `find` involved there somewhere, or something like [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/). But you'll also probably get better answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com than here, since this is more a _usage_ question than a _programming_ one.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows GUI concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command's `-exec grep` can solve your question, as in this example:

```
find /dir -name "*name_string*" -exec grep "content_string" {} /dev/null \;
```

This, however, will not only show you the name of the file, but also the line, containing the content_string. In case you just want the name of the string:

```
find /dir -name "*name_string*" -exec grep -l "content_string" {} \;
```

Obviously, you can use `-exec` with other commands (`head`, `tail`, `chmod`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `find` with `xargs`

```bash
find /dir -name "*name_string*"|xargs -0 -I '{}' grep "content_string" '{}'
```

With `xargs -0`, `grep` is executed only once and its parameter are all files found with the specified pattern:

```bash
grep file1 file2 file3 filen
#it will much faster because there is no overhead in fork and exec like this:
grep file1
grep file2
grep file3
..
```